# Finding limits of a trig function with a rooted denominator.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a final coming up soon and was needing help in understanding a faster method in calculating something like this:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} $$

I know the answer is 1, but the only method I currently know is to calculate this with the lowest reasonable x value I can input. The thing is if I use 0 the value is undefined, but if I use 1 the value is too far from 0 to correctly approximate, so then I'm left with values smaller than 1 to plug into and attempting to put fractions in a rooted denominator will become a time constraint on the test. This method takes too long and I was wanting to know if there is another method to find the limit.

Comment: Hint: Set $x = y^2.$ Then it's a limit you should know.

Comment: Do you know that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$?

Comment: I don't understand, that does give me the correct value, but it also converts the function into cos(x). When should I utilize this method and when should I not?

Comment: Why would it change it to a cosine?

Comment: I put sin(x)/x into desmos and it produced a cosine wave.

Comment: No, it is not a cosine wave.

Comment: But the peak value starts at a positive value, why wouldn't it be a cosine wave?

Comment: Plot $\cos x$ and $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ on the same graph. If they were the same, they would produce the same picture - they don't.

Comment: I found a nice proof that uses geometry. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1

Comment: I can use L'Hopitals rule to solve for this problem? I never thought about that.

Comment: And I can specifically use L'Hopitals rule because the function produces an undefined result at x=0. That actually explains a lot.

Comment: Now, I have another question. How does L'Hopital's rule in actuality aid in finding the discontinuity for a function? It just seems like a jimmy-rigged method in doing so. I guess what I'm really asking is, why does L'Hopital's rule work so well and not fail?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, we want to force the limit we all learned:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1.$$

To do this, we let $x = y^2$ in the proposed limit. Then as $x \to 0^+,$ we have $y \to 0.$ (You should check this.) Then

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\sin \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin y}{y}$$

and we're done.